# what is the difference between firstdata , payeezy, FirstData_Connect, FirstData_Webservice,FirstData_Payeezy

Tags: payment, gateway, firstdata, payeezy

i was searching for first data gateway api and i am stuck with the lots of names.

what is the difference between.

firstdata
payeezy
FirstData_Connect
FirstData_Webservice
FirstData_Payeezy

are those all separate gateways. if yes. then do i have to integrate different api for all of them.
can anyone give me the api docs. link for all of them.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Data Connect and First Data Webservice API are integration methods for an older payment gateway that First Data is slowly phasing out. They've already phased out Connect. Payeezy is First Data's e-commerce gateway going forward.